# Extracting text between two counts of a specific character in a string taken from an array with PHP

Tags: php, parsing

So I'm coding a script to extract particular data fields from strings of semi predictable data, and I'm trying to use PHP to grab the text between say the 70th and 71st counts of a specific character.

So a sample string of data would be as follows...

00000|data|data|data|text|data|data|||

How can I use PHP to grab the "text" between the 4th and 5th "|". The text field changes so I cannot just use a regex to match and extract it. The only logical method I can think of is the use the count of "|" which is predictable each time.

Any idea how I can accomplish this? I'd rate my PHP skills as moderate but no matter what I try I cant get this to work out.

Answer (score 1):

The split option given by @JohnConde in the comments section is one way to go here.  You could also use regex replacement:

```php
$input = "00000|data|data|data|text|data|data|||";
$match = preg_replace("/(?:[^|]+\|){4}([^|]+).*$/", "$1", $input);
echo $match;  # text
```

Comment: or `preg_match("/(?:\|?\K[^|]+){5}/", $input, $matches) ? $matches[0] : ''` will also work

Answer (score 1):

When you have a string that contains characters separated by a common delimiter you can use [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split that string into pieces separated by that delimiter and place the pieces into an array. You can then access a piece using standard array access syntax (remembering that arrays start counting at zero).

Step-by-step:

```
$pieces = explode("|", "00000|data|data|data|text|data|data|||");
echo $pieces[4]; // Get fifth string
```

Using [array dereferencing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-64) for shorter syntax:

```
echo explode("|", "00000|data|data|data|text|data|data|||")[4];
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but `[4]` _is_ "referencing".  Dereferencing would be using `list()` or `[$one, $two, $three, $four, $five, $six, $seven, $eight, $nine, $ten] = explode('|', ...);`

Comment: This explosion should be limited to 6 elements, since the OP only needs to access the 5th -- this way you do not waste time exploding 65-odd more times.